# Ordinality of a Set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

What is the difference between Ordinal number and cardinal number of a set?....I have a confusion in understanding the difference between the two.Can anyone help me to understand these two things? Thank you.

Comment: The phrase "Ordinality of a Set" makes no sense. A set has a cardinality. A set together with a well-ordering determines an ordinal, at which point one might be willing to utter the painful-sounding phrase that this structure has an "ordinality".

Comment: "Ordinality" (but that term is not common) would apply to an ordered set.  A maybe more common term is "order type".  Two ordered sets have the "same order type" iff there is a bijection between them that preserves the order.

Answer (score 5):

For finite sets it is the same thing, because a finite set can be well-ordered in a unique way, up to isomorphism. But for infinite sets there are many non-isomorphic well-orders that can be given to the set, but only one cardinality.

In other words, ordinals deal with structure -- order. Cardinals, and cardinality, deals with non-structure.

Comment: As an easy illustration, consider the set $\omega = \{0, 1, 2, \ldots\}$.  Then the 'natural' ordering, inherited from the natural numbers, gives rise to the ordinal (conveniently) denoted by $\omega$; but we can also look at other orders on the same set - for instance the one where every even number goes 'before' every odd number, but the numbers are otherwise ordered naturally: $0, 2, 4, \ldots, 1, 3, 5, \ldots$.  This is the order type (or ordinal - an ordinal is just an order type that satisfies some special conditions) $\omega\cdot 2$.

Comment: "a finite set can be well-ordered in a unique way". Not quite. Rather, all well-orderings are isomorphic (have the same order type, have the same length, ...).

Comment: Up to unique isomorphism! :)

Comment: @Andres: Of course, thank you.