# Ordinality of empty set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I search about why ordinality of an empty set is zero. there are some articles said this is convention. but i wondered the proof of this. Why ordinality of an empty set is zero?

Comment: See the post: [Ordinality of a set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/690183/ordinality-of-a-set): for *finite* sets, ordinal=cardinal, and thus the ordinality of a finite set is equal to the number of its elements.

Comment: You can see the [formal defintiion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number#Definitions), but they all agree on a basic fact: "ordinal, is one generalization of the concept of a natural number that is used to describe a way to arrange a collection of objects in order, one after another. Any finite collection of objects can be put in order just by the process of counting: labeling the objects with distinct whole numbers. Ordinal numbers are thus the "labels" needed to arrange collections of objects in order."

Comment: In set theory the empty set is by definition zero: $0:=\varnothing$. The set is transitive and well ordered by its epsilon relation. That makes it an ordinal number by definition.

Comment: It is the *smallest* ordinal as it would contain any smaller ordinal as element.